# Add or remove an item from a collection (set, array, or dictionairy) with a SwiftUI Toggle

Tags: swift, swiftui, toggle

I'm building a feature that's similar to the "favorites" feature in Apple's Fruta SwiftUI sample app. Users of that app can view a list of smoothies and mark any smoothie as "favorite". The list of favorites is stored and viewable on a separate screen.

The sample view below does two important things:

1. It checks if the smoothie is already in the list of favorites with `isFavorite`, so that this can be reflected by the button image.
2. It adds/removes that smoothie to/from the favorites list with `toggleFavorite`.

**Model:**

```
struct Smoothie: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: String
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var hasFreeRecipe = false
}

class FrutaModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var favoriteSmoothieIDs = Set<Smoothie.ID>()

    func toggleFavorite(smoothie: Smoothie) {
        if favoriteSmoothieIDs.contains(smoothie.id) {
            favoriteSmoothieIDs.remove(smoothie.id)
        } else {
            favoriteSmoothieIDs.insert(smoothie.id)
        }
    }
    
    func isFavorite(smoothie: Smoothie) -> Bool {
        favoriteSmoothieIDs.contains(smoothie.id)
    }
}
```

**Button view that's used to (un)favorite a smoothie:**

```
struct SmoothieFavoriteButton: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var model: FrutaModel
    
    var smoothie: Smoothie?
    
    var isFavorite: Bool {
        guard let smoothie = smoothie else { return false }
        return model.favoriteSmoothieIDs.contains(smoothie.id)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: toggleFavorite) {
            Label("Favorite", systemImage: isFavorite ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
        }
    }
    
    func toggleFavorite() {
        guard let smoothie = smoothie else { return }
        model.toggleFavorite(smoothie: smoothie)
    }
}
```

**My problem:** How can I achieve a similar result when using a Toggle instead of a Button? A Toggle requires a binding as a property, but since the `isFavorite` value for a particular smoothie comes from a Set (`favoriteSmoothieIDs`) that contains the full favorites list, I can't simply provide a binding for the Toggle.

Comment: I believe someone would have answered this for you already if this code contained the list you are referring to. (model.favoriteSmoothieIDs is empty).  Please provide enough code to demonstrate your issue.  This includes adding a definition for Smoothie and a view which displays the list.

Comment: I've just added the struct that defines `Smoothie`, if that's what you mean. I assume it doesn't matter what actual values are stored in model.favoriteSmoothieIDs. The list of favoriteSmoothieIDs can be empty, which is also the default state in which a user has not marked any smoothie as favorite yet.

Comment: Yes. I understand. I grabbed the smoothie definition from the original tutorial and ran your code before making my first comment. Running your code as is doesn't actually do anything. Also: You've added MeasuredIngredient which isn't defined, so again it's hard for someone to help you since you haven't provided a meaningful working example.

Answer (score 1):

This is the required code:

```
@State var isToggleFavorite = false

Toggle("", isOn: $isToggleFavorite)
            .onChange(of: isToggleFavorite) { value in
                guard let smoothie = smoothie else { return }
                model.toggleFavorite(smoothie: smoothie)
            }
```

Here I've added the code that answers your request and left the original intact.

```
struct SmoothieFavoriteButton: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var model: FrutaModel
    
    var smoothie: Smoothie?

    @State var isToggleFavorite = false // <== Newly Added

    var isFavorite: Bool {
        guard let smoothie = smoothie else { return false }
        return model.favoriteSmoothieIDs.contains(smoothie.id)
    }
    var body: some View {
        Toggle("", isOn: $isToggleFavorite)
            .onChange(of: isToggleFavorite) { value in
                guard let smoothie = smoothie else { return }
                model.toggleFavorite(smoothie: smoothie)
            } // <== Newly Added

        Button(action: toggleFavorite) {
            Label("Favorite", systemImage: isFavorite ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
        }
        .foregroundColor(isFavorite ? .accentColor : nil)
        .accessibility(label: Text("\(isFavorite ? "Remove from" : "Add to") Favorites"))
        } // <== Newly Added
    } 
    
    func toggleFavorite() {
        guard let smoothie = smoothie else { return }
        model.toggleFavorite(smoothie: smoothie)
    }
}
```

[[image: C]]

You could replace the button with a Text object:

```
 Text(isToggleFavorite ? Image(systemName: "heart.fill"): Image(systemName: "heart"))
```

But you would then need to persist the isFavorite value.

If having the heart on left side of the toggle is acceptable, you could remove the button entirely and place the heart image within the label of the toggle:

```
Toggle(isOn: $isToggleFavorite) {
                isToggleFavorite ?
                    Image(systemName: "heart.fill") : Image(systemName: "heart")
            }
            .onChange(of: isToggleFavorite) { value in
                guard let smoothie = smoothie else { return }
                model.toggleFavorite(smoothie: smoothie)
            }
```

You have a number of options available to you.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive help! This solves the 2nd part of the problem, but not the 1st part: Check if the smoothie is already in the list of favorites when the page first loads to show the correct state of the toggle. You can't solve this by setting the correct `isToggleFavorite` state in an onAppear modifier, because this would immediately fire the onChange state of the toggle. I now use `onTapGesture` instead of `onChange` on the Toggle, but that's won't work well for Toggles with a label.

Comment: I've already spent a couple of hours on it.  If I get a chance to get back to it, I will.  I need to concentrate on other things. Consider voting it up if my answer has been at all helpful so far, to give others a chance to find it. Someone else might give you answer I haven't provided.  That would be ideal. 